# Distortion pedals similar to Boss's DS-1

Tags: guitar, guitar-effects

Does anyone know of any distortion pedals that have tone similar to the Boss DS-1?  I love the smoothness, boost, and grind that this pedal offers, but I'm curious if there's a similar pedal that might give me a little more control than "tone" and gain.  I know that Boss has a few other distortion pedals, but I haven't messed with them enough to compare.  Does anyone own a DS-2 or something similar that might be able to give me a recommendation?

Comment: Let me say this: when you ask for a recommendation on an overdrive pedal prepare to be overwhelmed. I appreciate you constraining it to "like the DS-1" but I would like more information. What kinds of features are you looking for?

Comment: Bass and mid-range adjustment for sure...  If possible, something like a tone shaping feature.  I see this as being something comparable to how Digitech had the X-series that the "morph" knob that gave you the similar distortion, but provided you with a little more flexibility in tone.  And hey, maybe there's something else nifty that I don't know about.  Same distortion, more tone modification!

Comment: With all due respect I believe this question may be a bit too subjective and consequently I'm voting to close it. I could recommend that you check out "my favorite distortion" but how does that add value to the community outside of producing a sales pitch? You can find tons of ideas and recommendations at guitar forums like TGP. You may be able to rephrase this question to make it more empirical--so please consider that :).

Comment: Understood.  Close away :)

Comment: Thanks for being cool about it man :D. What you are looking at is kinda like asking: "Coke or Pepsi?" Certainly I can argue that coke is vastly superior to pepsi, but that doesn't make it factually correct.

Comment: No worries.  Yeah that's true, but either way, you just might help a newcomer find a decent cola, or at least pick a side to defend :)

Comment: @Jduv how is this different from http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/free-exercise-books?

Comment: I see your point DRL, but I think that the previous question might have a more finite answer than this one--specifically surrounding the keyword "free." I have seen forums go 50+ pages on why the Tim/Timmy are the greatest low gain distortions of all time, and even more on Jetters, Zendrives, Klons (technically a boost not a distortion), etcetera. I just don't think there's a straight answer to this question, but if others disagree then that's fine with me :).

Answer (score 3):

Blackstar have a range of valve pedals which offer awesome gain: [Blackstar HT Pedals](http://www.blackstaramps.co.uk/products/)

They are totally worth the extra cost and include feature such as an emulated speaker output, and infinite shape feature, which I can vouch for as being brilliant since I have a HT venue combo; which I use for all my Home recording.

Comment: Stellar!  I love the sound of Blackstar's amps, but I didn't know that had pedals too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Picking a distortion is much like picking a girlfriend. There are so many factors that can influence what you want or don't want that it becomes nearly impossible to give anyone a decent recommendation as a one liner. So, I'm going to try and enumerate some general attributes of distortions as I know them. Note that people have spent years experimenting with overdrives (points finger at self), and a new one comes out every year. I've yet to find an overdrive that's "perfect" by my standards, but I have a couple that come pretty darn close. To decrease the complexity of the issue I won't include boosts in my recommendation--those an entirely different animal.

**High Gain**

*Zendrive 2:* A tube bassed high gain version of the zendrive. I liked it, but ended up selling it. It didn't play nice with my amplifier.

*Jetter Stage Gold:* A great overdrive with some sick vintage high gain tones. Simple, and [reviewed](http://proguitarshop.com/store/effects-overdrive-pedals-c-602_6/jetter-gain-stage-gold-overdrive-p-1396) on PGS.

*Lovepedal provalve:* Two gains in one, [reviewed](http://proguitarshop.com/store/effects-overdrive-pedals-c-602_6/lovepedal-provalve-2-p-1519) on PGS. This would be my favorite high gain distortion.

**Medium Gain**

*Zendrive:* A very nice, tweakable and infamous overdrive. It's decently transparent and will give you a nice versatile set of tones. Sounds very much like a tubescreamer.

*Jetter Stage Purple:* A nice plexi emulator for blackfaces. Easy to use.

*Lovepedal Kanji:* Sean has some good stuff, and the Kanji is a more tweakable version of the Eternity overdrive. [Reviewed](http://proguitarshop.com/store/effects-overdrive-pedals-c-602_6/lovepedal-kanji-9-overdrive-pedal-p-1066) at PGS.

**Low Gain**

*Tim/Timmy:* You will be hard pressed to find a better overdrive than the Tim/Timmy by Paul Chochrane. It's the most transparent overdrive on the market, and the controls are very intuitive. Note that the breed of "transparent" overdrives are designed to accent a tube amplifier's dirt, so they may not work well with solid state rigs.

**All gain**

*Rock Box Boiling Point:* Will do anything from a plexi to functioning as a transparent boost. This guy is a monster, but it'll cost you. [Reviewed](http://proguitarshop.com/store/effects-overdrive-pedals-rockbox-boiling-point-overdrive-c-602_6_534/rockbox-boiling-point-overdrive-1524-p-1291) at PGS. Hands down the most versitile overdrive I own.

Comment: It's like a girlfriend. Someone else's always looks better. You really wish you could have more than one at a time. You've gone through more than you care to admit. There's at least one you still miss from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the [Digitech - Hot Head](http://digitech.com/en/products/hot-head),
it is a replica of DS1 with extra "low" knob.

There are many comparison videos on youtube you could check out

[image]